# mvn: command not found | Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, amazon-ec2, build

I tried to run simple mvn -v command as a build shell command, I get an error. I have tried numerous ways, but not sure on how to resolve this.

**Console output**

```
Started by user murthy

Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Job 1 test

[Job 1 test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins9213742596997762149.sh

+ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/New-Atom

+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)

+ git --version
git version 2.13.6

+ whoami
jenkins
+ date
Wed May 23 23:52:49 UTC 2018

+ mvn -v

/tmp/jenkins9213742596997762149.sh: line 7: mvn: command not found

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

**Maven installed** - Output from EC2

```
[ec2-user]$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.33-51.37.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

---

**Java installed** - Output from EC2

```
[ec2-user]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
```

---

**PATH is set**

```
[ec2-user]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

[ec2-user]$ echo $MAVEN_HOME  # mvn is set
/usr/local/maven

[ec2-user]$ echo $JAVA_HOME  # java is set
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64
```

We can see that Java and Maven are both set, but I am not able to see Maven in my job.  What could be the problem?

Comment: You have Java and Maven set up on `ec2-user`.  What about on the `jenkins` user?

Comment: Do an echo $PATH  on jenkins in the shell and see if maven is present in the PATH

Comment: The only thing which is needed is the entry in `$PATH` nothing more is needed. Remove the `MAVEN_HOME` does not make sense...